# I changed my username but still the previous username is shown on the C:/Users

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, path

I installed Windows 10 with `user1` username, after a day I went to control panel and changed the name of my username(Administrator and the only user) `user1` to `user2` and now it shows `user2` in the Windows startup screen(as I expected).

But the problem is that when I checked `C:/Users` I see only my previous `user1` and don't see the `user2`(Windows didn't change my username here). And this caused a new problem when I wanted to install `VS code` from Anaconda navigator because it seeks for `user2` but seems my username is still `user1` in the `C:/Users`.

Comment: The path of the user profile directory is never changed. It will always remain the same no matter how often you rename the account.

Comment: You are always better to create a new account with the name you want. Windows has always done this, once a user account is created the users folder the name can never be changed due to registry and security concerns, the name is carved in stone in the users folder.

Comment: You can however change the user profile path, which may solve your issue>>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2454362/renaming-a-user-account-does-not-automatically-change-the-profile-path